# Restringir CSS ao IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

Está faltando algo neste parâmetro ? Preciso que esse estilo se aplique somente ao IE 11, quando incluo este código funciona, mas os outros navegadores tbm pegam

```
<!-- [if gte IE 8]-->
    <style>
        .box-form .logo-footer {
            margin-top: -2vh!important;
            margin-bottom: -9vh!important;
            margin-left: 44px!important;
        }
    </style>
<!--[endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas **para o IE10 e IE11** você pode fazer assim!

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .box-form .logo-footer { 
        margin-top: -2vh!important;
        margin-bottom: -9vh!important;
        margin-left: 44px!important;
    }
}
```

Aqui tem uma documentação mais completa.

https://gist.github.com/vidaaudrey/c16774076391d09e7ec7dbb7ed7a3189

Teste do Hack no IE11 no Windows 10 e Chrome 63

No Chrome 63
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**No IE 11, repare o quadrado vermelho no canto inferior direito "11"**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Código que usei**

```
<style>
.teste {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .teste { 
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: black;
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="teste"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Boa Hugo !
Mas aqui não pegou, to lendo a documentação pra ver se encontro algo, mas ainda nada =/

Comment: Nessa documentação tem para todos os IEs aqui na minha maquina rodando Windows 10 deu certo no IE11 sem problemas. Lembre de colocar esse código dentro do <style></style>

Comment: Hugo ! Salvou minha vida ! Eu estava usando no css externo, não sabia que precisava ser embutido ... brigadão viu !

Comment: @Flávia que bom que deu certo! Se minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marcar a Resposta com "Aceita" ✔ Inclusive eu editei a resposta com umas imagens e mais umas infos.