# A COR DO MEU SITE NÃO ABRE CERTO NO IE11 E EDGE?

Tags: css, navegador-de-internet, internet-explorer

Boa tarde Devs, estou puelo já com isso...consegui converte as cores no Firefox...mais o IE sem chance, e o cliente ainda quer olhar no IE...tem alguma forma para solucionar? usei esses codigos no moz.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
   #header.reveal.alt{
        background: #848484;
    }

     body{
        background: #848484;
    }

    #header{
        background:#848484 ;

    }
```

são essas 3 divs que preciso mudar no IE tbm...

[Link](http://avannx-grupo.com/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Cara o problema é que vc declarou a cor dentro de um "hake" que faz com que a cor só funcione no Fire fox `@-moz-document url-prefix() { }` tudo que estiver dentro disso só vai renderizar no browser da Mozilla, ous seja, nos outros browsers vai mostrar a cor branca `#ffffff` *(na verdade é "transparente" e o fundo do browser é que é branca e não do documento)* que é a cor *default* da maioria dos `user-agents`

Para a cor funcionar em todos os browsers, declare ela fora do `@-moz-document url-prefix() { }`

```css
body{
  background: #848484;
}
#header{
  background:#848484 ;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

---

**Veja como é no Chrome**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu ja tenho declarado fora essas cores, elas rodam 100% normal no Chrome.
porem nos outros não...por isso tive que declarar assim para o Mozila ler.
Agora o Mozila e o Chrome estão OK...porem o IE nada acontece...

Comment: @Igor aqui funcionou normal nos dois, IE e EDGE, entrei pelo link que vc postou e a cor tb estava igual nos dois. Se vc quiser vc pode tentar fazer algum hake tb para o IE. Aqui tem uma resposta sobre isso que pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266906/restringir-css-ao-ie/266911#266911 no que vc coloca lá para o IE use !important pode se que ajude

Comment: Serio cara? eu to testando ja faz 1 semana e não aparece pra mim...jura que apareceu normal nos 2? como pode isso que estranho....mesmo com aquele aplicação?

Comment: @Igor limpe o cache do seu navegador e tente novamente, ou acesse de outro PC para testar. Coloque tbm margin:0 no seu html e body pelo css

Comment: voce pode me mandar a tela mano? Vou veirificar aqui...ja tinhe feito tudo isso não e possivel

Comment: @Igor confere ai no link testado no Chrome https://imgur.com/SDOPOHo repare que eu coloco margem:0 no body também, mas o seu site ficar sem essa borda branca

Comment: No Chrome ele ta show, tbm tirei essa borda mano...porem queria que ele reproduzi-se assim no IE...voce acesso e não quebro nada? nem a cor fico branca...aqui ta assim

Comment: @Igor cara mas vc está colocando outra cor no Body pq? Veja que no seu `main.css` na linha 81, vc está declarando outra cor para o Body!! http://prntscr.com/owa7mj tem que arrumar lá. E vc está usando cor nesse formato `#48484896` esse formato o IE não entende, ele só entende até 6 algarismos como hex

Comment: acabei de tira aquele cor no BODY, e declarei o codigo do seu link que vi...sera que roda ou esta errado?

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    #header.reveal.alt{
        background: #848484;
    }
 
  body{
        background: #848484;
    }
 
 #header{
        background:#848484 ;
  
    }
}

Comment: @Igor aqui no IE11 esse código funcionou. Eu ainda colocaria `background:#848484 !important` só para garantir

Comment: Pow show ! voce consegue me mandar a tela cara? estou sem o IE11 aqui e não consigo instalar...tem algum preview online ? to puxando os cabelos mano...para esse IE

Comment: @Igor http://prntscr.com/owai8j ta ai